# Cross-domain SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

Trying to make a cross-domain version of the Microsoft Getting started with SignalR:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio
And I am experiencing a lot of problems. I already configured CORS on the server side.
But the console shows me this:

```
GET http://10.50.2.87:8080/node_modules/signalr/dist/browser/signalr net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Not really sure why it doesn't work.
scripts.js file:

```
import * as  signalR from "./node_modules/signalr/dist/browser/signalr"

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44368/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

ChatHub class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Configured the CORS like this:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://10.50.2.87:8080/")
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
```

And I added these two lines at the end of my html file:

```
<script src="/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./scripts.js"></script>
```

The button on the page is active, which means that frontend is being connected to the hub on the server side, but when I click on it nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="/node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```

The `src` here is the endpoint that is causing an error.
The error is not found, which means it cannot find the js file, and that is normal because asp core is not going to share files from there unless you explicitly tell it to.
The tutorial you linked says to use the js library like this:

```
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

The `js` at the front is a js folder where the js file is located.  If you follow the tutorial it will be put there.  You can also put it there manually by putting it in `wwwroot/js` in your source.

Comment: But I don't want my frontend part be in wwwroot/js folder, I created separate Frontend folder with html, css and js file, and also added signalr file there as well and importing it from here. That is why I am trying to use a cross domain, serving both frontend and backend on localhost. 
Anyway as I understand the frontend server is trying to find the signalr.js file on it's http://10.50.2.87:8080 address, and I am not sure if http server can access files. Might this be the cause of the problem? 
Using react js it is a few lines of code and everything works perfectly.

Comment: your problem isn't with cross domain.  your problem is that you need to put the js file somewhere it can be downloaded statically from your server, or use a cdn.

Comment: Good news I solved this one, bad news I am getting new error
signalR.HubConnectionBuilder is not a constructor

Comment: Make another question and ill help u